# Named range in conditional formatting formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below. And I would like to set named ranges (cells) instead of ranges (cells) H$7 and $G$7. Because if for example I add new column before these cells and recover macro with this code it does not work correctly. Have you got any idea? Thanks in advance

```
With Range(SomeRange).FormatConditions _
.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=((H$7<=$G$7)*((H$7+7)>$G$7))") 
With .Interior                                                      
     .Color = RGB(197, 217, 241)                                    
End With
End With
```

Comment: You should be able to substitute the range names for H7 and G7.  did you try that?

Comment: Yes, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Just type the name of a named range in the formula, nothing special as long as the named range exists.  If I name H7 "B" and G7 "A" then this works for me...

```
Sub Test()
    'Range
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A1")
    R.FormatConditions.Delete
    'Formula
    Dim F As String
    F = "=((B<=A)*((B+7)>A))"
    'Condition
    Dim Cond As FormatCondition
    Set Cond = R.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, F)
    Cond.Interior
    Cond.Color = RGB(197, 217, 241)
End Sub
```

Note though, with the formula argument of 'FormatConditions.Add', everything within the double quotes gets evaluated exactly as if typed within a cell. The argument is passed as a string and interpreted as a literal string value. So you can test your formula string by copying and pasting it to a cell and it should work the same (return 1 or 0), modify it in the cell, and copy and past back.

You don't have to create/set the names problematically, but if you want to, then I'd probably use the [workbooks collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx) unless you repeat the same name on multiple sheets, then use the [worksheet collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197993.aspx).

About named ranges...

[The Object (Name)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839264.aspx)

[The Collection (Names)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195422.aspx)

[Setting Referencing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823060.aspx)

Comment: Also, note that this code clears the target cell's conditional formatting.  I'm assuming that's something you'll want to do, but I don't know what other rules you may be applying.  Also, it's generally considered best practice to avoid using the 'With' statement. Excel's macro recording just uses it because it has trouble creating and managing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the address of the named ranges and concatenating them in your formula string.

Eg.

```
Adr1= range("namedrange1"). Address
Adr2= range("namedrange2"). Address
With Range(SomeRange).FormatConditions _
.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=((" & adr1 & "<=" & ad2 & ")*((" & adr1 & "+7)>" & adr2 & "))")
```